# What is a grace period for a bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

And why is it not described [here](https://superuser.com/privileges/set-bounties)?

Also, just out of curiosity, when did this come into effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature was proposed on Meta.SO to allow users to manually award the bounty after the bounty has expired.

> I propose a period of 24 hours after the bounty has expired during which the question will not be on the featured tab but the promoter can still manually award the bounty. The "cost" of this would be that no new bounty could be set up until the old one were awarded.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remainin) for more information on the request and the response by the team.

> due to a lot of <s>whining</s> valued community feedback on this issue, I decided it can't hurt to extend the auto-award period 24 hours past the true end of the bounty. So, the question will stop being a bounty question at the *original scheduled time* but the auto-accept calculations will always occur *24 hours after that*.

---

There's also [a blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/) on that topic:

> To assist forgetful bounty owners, there is a new 24 hour grace period at the end of every bounty. During this grace period, the question will not be featured, but the bounty can still be awarded at any time.

Comment: Any ideas why the set bounty page was not updated?

Comment: @soandos Because nobody changed it. Apparently, users should be able to edit the Meta.SO privileges page and if accepted, it will be deployed on all sites. SO you can head over and suggest an edit that mentions the changed behavior.

Comment: like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117793/update-the-set-bounty-page-to-include-the-grace-period) or is it supposed to be done a different way?

Comment: @soandos On Meta.SO you are supposed to *suggest edits* to the `/privileges` pages themselves (or directly edit them, I don't know). I am unable to do so, but have been told that's a glitch.

Comment: I can't seem to suggest an edit their either.

Comment: @soandos [I see an edit wiki link](http://i.imgur.com/GYKnd.png) at the bottom of the page, isn't it visible for you?

Comment: @Sathya, nope. Nothing there.

Comment: might be a rep thing then @soandos - the privilege wiki is up-to-date, but hasn't been deployed to the network. I've asked waffles to push the changes